# JSQMessagesViewController scroll to bottom only if not at the bottom already

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessagesViewController with Swift.

For the moment, I set `automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = false` so that each time I am receiving a new message, to view doesn't scroll to the bottom.

What I would like is: to know when I am at **the bottom of the view**, so that

**if bottom of view and**:
(  Someone is typing:`isTyping = true`  **or**  I receive a new message )

**then** I can set
`automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true`

**else** I set `automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = false`

In iOS, the basic behaviour is each time there is a new message, it scrolls to this new message, but in Android, if I am not currently at the extreme bottom, I have a label saying "you have a new message".

I don't know how to figure out if I am currently at the bottom or not.
Any ideas?

I found this issue on **Github**, it's almost the same:
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1458

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: papay, did you solve this issue and can share a hint?